# placing class inside another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program I have a class called "right-answer that I want in the td class but I am having real trouble with it.

This is where I add the "right word" class to "spellWord". But how to I add it to the "td" class instead.

```
var spellWord = $('.highlight-problem .drop-box');
            if (!spellWord.filter(':not(.occupied)').length) {
                var wordIsCorrect = 0;
                spellWord.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).parents('td').data("letter") == $(this).find("div").data("letter")) {
                        console.log('letter is: ' + $(this).find("div").data("letter"))
                        wordIsCorrect++;
                    }
                });
                console.log(spellWord.length + ' , ' + wordIsCorrect);
                if (spellWord.length == wordIsCorrect) {
                    spellWord.addClass('right-word');
                    $(right).css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $(wrong).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    score.right++;
                    $('.score').html(score.right + "/2").show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        successSound.play();
                    }, 200);
```

I have tried things like.

```
spellWord.addClass('td').addClass('right-word');
```

and

```
$('.td').addClass('right-word');
```

But cannot seem to get it working. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/93/

Answer (score 0):

If the spellWord element is inside the td, use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
spellWord.parent().addClass('right-word');
```

Note that `parent()` will only give you the direct ancestor, use `parents()` instead if you nede to go higher.

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), or [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) may also be helpful, depending on where the td is in relation to the spellWord element.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.closest()`

```
spellWord.closest('td').addClass('right-word');
```

`td` is the parent of the `spellWord.`. So you need to go to its td ancestor and then add the class